# Marginal density of X error in the test?

Tags: probability-distributions

So I took a test. And it was easy, but for some reason I got 0pts out of 5pts in a once single exercise.

OK, here it is: "Given the joint density function
$$f(x,y)=12/7$$

when $$0\leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } 0\leq y \leq 1$$
And 0 elsewhere. Calculate it's marginal density of $X$."

The answers:
(a): $$f_X(x)=(12x^2+6x)/7$$

(b): $$f_X(x)=(2x^2+3x)/7$$

(c): $$f_X(x)=(4+6x)/7$$

(d): $$\text{None of the above.}$$

My short solution sketch:
Apply definition 5.4 (attached as image) and apply the bounds, hence
$$f_X(x)=\int_0^1 12/7 dx=[12x/7]_0^1=12/7$$ thus, it's option D.

Definition 5.4 can be found here: http://puu.sh/BQaS3/5af75ea1be.png
Am I right or? Because I did a similar exercise in the exercise classes where we have another number we should integrate (without variables) like here. I obtained a correct solution, but now I got 0 out of 5 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x,y)$ doesn't integrate to $1$, it is not a valid joint density function.

Comment: Yea, but I didn't make any typos, this is the question I got. But my problem is still that I got 0 out of 5pts. Anyway, are my method correct? I.e. my solution sketch?

Comment: To get marginal distribution of $X$, you should integrate with respect to $y$.  But it is really not a valid distribution, hence I would guess none of the above since the question doesn't make sense?

Comment: I would tell my instructor about it next time. Here is the question (I can't see the answers since the test is graded)

http://puu.sh/BQbdO/36a5b21738.png

Comment: most likely a typo somewhere in the question.

Comment: Thank you, I've sent an mail to my instructor and showed my solution. I've corrected the variable x to y, thanks for mention me about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the pdf is not right. I think the (valid) pdf is

$$f(x,y)=12/7\cdot (x^2+xy)$$

when $0\leq x \leq 1 \text{ and } 0\leq y \leq 1$

To calculate the marginal density of $X$ you have to integrate w.r.t $y$- $\color{blue}{\texttt{not x}}$

$$f_X(x)=\int_0^1 12/7\cdot (x^2+xy) \, dy $$

$$ \frac{12}{7} \cdot \left[ x^2y+\frac{1}{2}xy^2 \right]_0^1=\frac{12}7\cdot (x^2+\frac12 x)-0$$

$$=\frac{1}{7} \cdot (12x^2+6x)$$

when $0\leq x \leq 1 $

Therefore the answer is **a)**

Comment: Where did you get $$f(x,y)=12/7\cdot (x^2+xy)$$ from? Maybe a typo from my teacher for I can't see how you else will get it.

Comment: @JoeyAdams See [here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/consider-joint-probability-density-function-f-x-y-12-7-x-2-xy-0-lessthanorequalto-x-lessth-q12498543)

Comment: Ahh I see! But your answer $$1/7(12x^2+6x)$$ is not equal to b).

Sorry! you edited it!

Comment: It is a), sorry. I´ve made an edit.

Comment: I see :) I will be back later, I've sent an email to my instructor with an answer to this problem. I "hope" it's a typo mistake from my instructor, because your calculations makes sense.

Comment: It must be a typo since f(x,y) does not integrate to 1. Maybe you can send another e-mail with the pdf I´ve posted. Looking forward for your reply

Comment: For some reason, my instructor did not answer my mail Yesterday but I believe that it’s a typo. I warned my fellow friends at the University

Comment: Onday the instructor must confess that he made a mistake. But it takes some time.